# duals of subspaces of DF-spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a complete barrelled DF-space and $Y$ its closed subspace. As can be seen the dual $(Y',\beta(Y',Y))$ is metrizable. Does it follow it is also complete?

Comment: I doubt very much. I think that it was Ruess who coined the term df-space for spaces whose strong dual is Frechet. I had a short look at Jarchow's book but did not find an example of a closed subspace of a df-space which is not df. There are, however, examples of closed subspaces of DF-spaces failing DF.

Comment: A further remark (following from the open mapping theorem) is that $Y'$ is complete if and only if $Y'_\beta$ gets its topology from the quotient map $X'_\beta\to Y'_\beta$. This means that for every bounded set $B$ in $X$ there is a bounded $C$ in $Y$ such that every $f\in Y'$ which is bounded by $1$ on $C$ can be extended to some $F\in X'$ which is bounded by one on $B$. (This extra bound does not immediately come with the Hahn-Banach extension).

Comment: Perhaps, you could give some motivation for your question.

Comment: I'm dealing at the moment with topological algebras which are, as lcs', complete and barrelled DF-spaces. In this framework multiplication is jointly continuous and so we get a continuous linear map $\pi\colon A\widehat{\otimes}A\to A,\,a\otimes b\mapsto ab$. I am interested in the properties of the closed subspace $\ker\pi\subset A\widehat{\otimes}A$ or its dual. Two further specific questions are: do we have $\ker\pi\subset(\ker\pi)''$ topologically and do we have $(\ker\pi)''\simeq\ker\pi''$ topologically?